# Unhandled exception when using getline

Tags: c++, string, getline

I keep getting the Unhandled exception when I try to get the first letter after using `getline` function.

Error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7535DB52 in Lab2 - Containers and Regex.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location
>   0x00B5F43C.

---

```
class CodeMap
{
private:
    vector<string> code;
    vector<char> character;

public:
    CodeMap() { character.resize(11000); }
    ~CodeMap() {};

    void setChar(string filename)
    {
        string fileName = filename;
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open(fileName.c_str());
        string line = " ";
        char codeChar;

        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            getline(fin, line);
            codeChar = line.at(0);  //Unhandled exception, tried to use [] instead, still error.

        }
        fin.close();

    }
```

I wondered what is going on here.

Anyway to fix this?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: The eof() cluster-ef just doesn't matter that much, boilerplate when parsing a text file is to always skip empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

As the linked answer says (in the comment by @NeilButterworth), you cannot use the EOF condition to determine if you can do another read, only if the last read "failed". In the code above when getline finally fails (which it *will*), you'll have an empty `line` variable, which you then do an access on.

Try to do `while(std::getline(fin, line)) { ...` instead. That way, when getline fails, you're not using the contents of the (empty) `line`.

Comment: That solves the problem! thank you so much!

Comment: `getline()` can succeed and still return a blank string, if there is a blank line in the file. Best to check for a blank string before calling `at(0)` on it